# How to avoid Reusable Cell's copy behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is the problem, when I use a TableViewController and add a behavior on cell been selected. The behavior showed twice

How can I avoid this?

```
// MARK: - Table Deleget

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { 
        cell?.viewWithTag(100)?.isHidden = true
        (cell?.viewWithTag(200) as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor.red
    })

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    UIView.animate( withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        cell?.viewWithTag(100)?.isHidden = false
        (cell?.viewWithTag(200) as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 128/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1)
    })

}
```

[image: first one]
[image: identical one]

Comment: Please clarify the question. Questions asking for debugging help need to include the code causing the issue, the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour.

Comment: Please use if let method in your code, then check.

Comment: @Mehul  Thank you, app isn't crash now, but still shows the same behavior twice

Comment: @KyleBing what does 'still shows the same behavior twice' mean? I took a kook at the codes in the question.What I understand is that you want the label textColor on the selected cell is red,on the unselected is green.Why not custom a subclass of tableView cell and in the custom cell class, you can override the selected method :override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)  if selected { // hide the viewWithTag(100) and change color to red  }else{//code}

Comment: @OmniRingo Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the animation from the 'cellForRow' method to ['willDisplayCell'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview) method. I think it can help to you avoid the twice animation.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it, add a var to remember the cell which has been taped, and use `cellWillDisplay` to refresh every cell will displayed, check each cell if it has been selected, if has, show it the selected way.

```
// MARK: - Table Deleget

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    index = indexPath.row
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            cell.viewWithTag(100)?.isHidden = true
            (cell.viewWithTag(200) as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor.red
        })
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        UIView.animate( withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            cell.viewWithTag(100)?.isHidden = false
            (cell.viewWithTag(200) as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 128/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1)
        })
    }
}

// Added this
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let index = index, index == indexPath.row {
        cell.viewWithTag(100)?.isHidden = true
        (cell.viewWithTag(200) as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor.red
    } else {
        cell.viewWithTag(100)?.isHidden = false
        (cell.viewWithTag(200) as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 128/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

[image: I have fixed it]